# Recover Slurm job submission script from an old job?

Tags: slurm

I accidentally removed a job submission script for a Slurm job in terminal using `rm` command. As far as I know there are no (relatively easy) ways of recovering that file anymore, and I hadn't saved it anywhere. I have used that job submission script many many times before, so there are a lot of Slurm job submissions (all of them finished) that have used it. Is it possible to recover that job script from an old finished job somehow?

Comment: AFAIK, you can recover the file you submited, but not the contents of that file. I mean: you can recover `my_script.sh", but not the contents of this file, as SLURM does not need to keep the contents, only the command he has to start.

Comment: That's a shame. How about the individual "srun" commands in the script? Would there be a way to see them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Slurm is configured with the [ElasticSearch plugin](https://slurm.schedmd.com/elasticsearch.html), then you will find the submission script for all completed jobs in the ElasticSearch instance used in the setup.

Another option is to install [sarchive](https://lib.rs/crates/sarchive)